# json4s parse json partially

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a json model, where contents of certain attribute depend on the other attribute. Something like this:

```
"paymentMethod": "CREDIT_CARD",
"metaData": {
    "cardType": "VISA",
    "panPrefix": "",
    "panSuffix": "",
    "cardHolder": "",
    "expiryDate": ""
}
```

So when `paymentMethod` equals to `CREDIT_CARD`, the `metadata` object will contain attributes as described. In case of other payment method, there'll be different metadata.

I want to handle this situation in a future-proof way. What I'm trying to do is to not parse the `metadata` field right away, but keep it somehow "unparsed" until I've parsed the `paymentMethod` field. Then I'd take the metadata and applied appropriate parsing approach.

However I don't know which type to use for a Scala class field for such "late parsed" attributes. I've tried `String`, `JsonInput`, `JObject`, and they all are not suitable (either don't compile or can't be parsed). Any ideas which type can I use? Or, in other words:

```
case class CreditCardMetadata(
  cardType: String,
  panPrefix: String,
  panSuffix: String,
  cardHolder: String,
  expiryDate: String)

case class PaypalMetadata(...) // etc.

case class PaymentGatewayResponse(
  paymentMethod: String,
  metadata: ???)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `CustomSerializer` to parse the metadata directly. Something like :

```
case class PaymentResponse(payment: Payment, otherField: String)

sealed trait Payment
case class CreditCardPayment(cardType: String, expiryDate: String) extends Payment
case class PayPalPayment(email: String) extends Payment

object PaymentResponseSerializer extends CustomSerializer[PaymentResponse]( format => ( 
  {
    case JObject(List(
           JField("paymentMethod", JString(method)),
           JField("metaData", metadata),
           JField("otherField", JString(otherField))
         )) =>
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      val payment = method match {
        case "CREDIT_CARD" => metadata.extract[CreditCardPayment]
        case "PAYPAL" => metadata.extract[PayPalPayment]
      }
      PaymentResponse(payment, otherField)
  },
  { case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException } // no serialization to json
))
```

Which can be used as:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + PaymentResponseSerializer

val json = parse("""
      {
        "paymentMethod": "CREDIT_CARD",
        "metaData": {
            "cardType": "VISA",
            "expiryDate": "2015"
        },
        "otherField": "hello"
      }
      """)

val json2 = parse("""
    {
      "paymentMethod": "PAYPAL",
      "metaData": {
          "email": "foo@bar.com"
      },
      "otherField": "world"        
    }
    """)

val cc =  json.extract[PaymentResponse]
// PaymentResponse(CreditCardPayment(VISA,2015),hello)
val pp =  json2.extract[PaymentResponse]
// PaymentResponse(PayPalPayment(foo@bar.com),world)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, your response has put me on the right track. I only needed some ad-hoc solution, therefore I posted my own answer based on yours, to illustrate this can be implemented with less code. 

For others reading this, this answer is the right way to go, but if you need something quick, my answer will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map[String, String]`. 
It will contain anything you may need.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Peter Neyens has inspired me to implement my own solution. It's not as generic as his, but in my case I needed something really simple and ad-hoc. Here's what I've done:

It's possible to define a case class with the field of unknown type is represented by a `JObject` type. Something like this:

```
case class PaymentGatewayResponse(
  default: Boolean,
  paymentMethod: String,
  visibleForCustomer: Boolean,
  active: Boolean,
  metaData: JObject)
```

When such json is parsed into such case class, this field is not parsed immediately, but contains all the necessary information. Then it's possible parse it in a separate step:

```
case class CreditCardMetadata(
  cardType: String,
  cardObfuscatedNumber: String,      
  cardHolder: String,
  expiryDate: String)

val response: PaymentGatewayResponse = doRequest(...)
response.map { r =>
      r.paymentMethod match {
        case "CREDIT_CARD" => r.metaData.extract[CreditCardMetadata]
        case unsupportedType: String => throw new UnsupportedPaymentMethodException(unsupportedType)
      }
    }
```